# New deprecation date?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

All GCM pages I can find show April 11th as the earliest GCM services will stop.  Yesterday I received an email stating it was now May 29th.  I don't see this date anywhere though, is there a place I can get it confirmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: May 29th is the official.

[Home Page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm)'s banner was just updated:

> "API's... will be removed as soon as May 29, 2019"

Comment: Seems weird that EoS is 1.5 months after most things stop.

Comment: Website official is May 29th now :)

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with checking, I was actually on chat support most of the day.